# How to render content plugin into a module

Tags: development, module, plugin, joomla-3.5

I'm porting a code from a template override of `com_content` **category blog_item** into a module.
Everything is all right done, except for one thing I'm struggling with.

I have this code from `com_content` tmpl:

```
<?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
```

In the module I tried:

```
<?php echo $item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
```

But it is not working and it fires a notice ("Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...")

Any suggestion to have it working into a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about how you build your module and what the `$item` stands for there.

Assuming you are loading the articles using the com_content's model and you have an array of **`$items`** with each `$item` being an **`Article Object`**, returned by the `ContentModel`, then you can do at the top of your module's template:

```
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
```

Then in your loop of the `$items` (since you said you are porting over a category blog, I guess you will have a list of articles).

```
foreach ($items as $item) {

    // Get everything from the enabled OnContentBefore plugins in an array
    // passing the $item and $params as reference
    $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentBeforeDisplay', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$item->params, 0)); 

    $beforeDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));

    echo $beforeDisplayContent . ' - ' . $item->title;

}
```

### More reading: JPlugin Documentation:

- [Triggering content plugins in extensions](https://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension)
- [Content Plugin Events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The module is essentially the mod_article_latest plus some js and a different template. 
So I think your solution is correct: adding the code from view.html.php of com_content . 
Now I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: Then you should be fine with the code above. If my answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted answer (http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) @N.Fury

Comment: starting from your code I did this into the loop:

$item->event = new stdClass();     
$item->event->beforeDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));

and now I can use "<?php echo $item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>" into the tmpl/default.php 
It not automatically render the plugin, but I can add a shortcode via the article editor, like this {maxivote} and everything's all right !!!